# Build unsuccessful after updating android studio to 3.0. Error:Found unexpected optical bounds (red pixel)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I updated my Android Studio to 3.0 in Ubuntu. When I loaded a project it fails to build and the same project has no issues when it was built in previous version(v2.3) of Android Studio. And the error says,

> Error:found unexpected optical bounds (red pixel) on top border at x=14.
>
> Error:.
>
> Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error

Comment: Did you try to clean the project and rebuild it ?

Comment: As of AS 3.1 and latest gradle version 4.7 apt has to be enabled. The workaround for this is to identify the nine patch with the optical bounds(nine patch images with red lines). Once you identify the image causing the issue you can recreate or edit it accordingly

Comment: This problem returns on Android 3.3, check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54323764/3996257

Comment: I solved this issue and posted a solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54323764/found-unexpected-optical-bounds-red-pixel-on-top-border-at-x-14/56331094#56331094.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally I found out the problem. It was due to some 9 patch icons that I used in my project resources. I have made use of some 3rd party tool to draw these icons. Now I replaced those icons with that of the same generated using Android studio([see how](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html)) and everything is working for me.

Also if you don't want to use AAPT2. You can disable by setting `android.enableAapt2=false` in your `gradle.properties` file as suggested by @capt.swag

Answer (score 11):

After updating to Android Studio 3.0 I was also facing the same issue. I solved the problem by setting **android.enableAapt2=false**

> Improved incremental resource processing using AAPT2, which is enabled by default. If you are experiencing issues while using AAPT2, you can disable it by setting android.enableAapt2=false in your gradle.properties file and restarting the Gradle daemon by running ./gradlew --stop from the command line.

More about it in [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0.html)

Comment: @arts777 then give your solution. Everyone blame others but not give solution :)

Comment: @RanjithKumar the real solution is to fix 9patch image. I'm not so much familiar with 9patches to provide exact guide, but disabling aapt2 is a very bad idea.

Comment: I would like to support that argument, but finding what's the problem with 9patch images should take some time.

Comment: Its `android.enableAapt2=false` not `:`

Comment: @NileshDeokar Updated the answer.