# Found unexpected optical bounds (red pixel) on top border at x=14

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-drawable

Recently, I'm updating to Android Studio 3.3 and Gradle 3.3, in this version the gradle.property `'android.enableAapt2=false'` has no effect because AAPT2 is now always used. The real problem comes when I delete this line, because can't compile, the next error that throws is:

> Android resource compilation failed
>
> error: found unexpected optical bounds (red pixel) on top border at x=14.

In the previous versions we can solve this problem as in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46949586/3996257). Now I can't compile my app cause exists this error.

---

Update from: 2019-01-24

Finally I found the real problem with the new log error in Android Studio 3.2:

> Android resource compilation failed
>   Output:  error: .
>
> Command: /Users/myProject/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-
>   3.2.1-4818971-osx.jar/0a24b213ff9fab058ea2520938e2e6e3/aapt2-3.2.1->4818971-osx/aapt2 compile --legacy \
>          -o \
>          /Users/myProject/android->app/myProject/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug \
>          /Users/myProject/android-app/myProject/app/src/main/res/drawable->hdpi/balloon_incoming_normal.9.png
>
> Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx Daemon #1

The file produce this problem is:

[image]

[URL to download](https://github.com/DeromirNeves/whatsapp-android/tree/master/app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi)

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems to be a problem in a 9 patch image. Best to fix that image.

Comment: How can I search this image?

Comment: The photo is not of the file!

Comment: You have the url to download now ;)

Comment: Same was happening to me, in the same file.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue following this steps:

1. Copy the resource, duplicating the file.
2. Rename the file to original name

Example:
      balloon_outgoing_normal.9 - copy.png 
      **to** 
      balloon_outgoing_normal.png

3. Remove the file 9-patched that doesnt works.

Example:: balloon_outgoing_normal.9.png

4. Open the file in Android Studio
5. Right-click on each file (mdpi, hdpi, etc..)
6. Select **Create-9-Patch File...** and save each file on your respective folder (mdpi, hdpi, etc..)

After this steps, I had success on compilation.